# change the location of an element everytime the page is loaded

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have an HTML page with 5 images *(48px × 48px each)* on it. I want to appear the images at random locations on the webpage everytime the page is loaded.

I don't know how to implement this, I just know I'm going to need CSS and JavaScript *(for randomization)* for this. Any ideas or suggesions?

Here is sample HTML code:

```
  <a href="http://twitter.com/"><img alt="Twitter" src="/images/twitter-48.png" /></a>
  <a href="http://facebook.com/><img alt="Facebook" src="/images/facebook-48.png" /></a>
  <a href="https://plus.google.com/"><img alt="Google Plus" src="/images/plus-48.png" /></a>
  <a href="https://github.com/"><img alt="GitHub" src="/images/github-48.png" /></a>
```

Comment: About PHP: don't forget that it's better to perform work on client always if it's possible and safe to offload your server. About the random positioning - do you already have a containers or image elements and just need assign `src` randomly or you want to set `position:fixed;` and place images randomly within the body?

Comment: @Santosh, please provide more details. What do you mean by "random location"? Is it supposed to be some container-wrapper inside which images will be absolutely positioned or something else? Provide some markup

Comment: @caligula, h[is|er] request seemed pretty straight forward to me, he'd like to randomize the location of elements on a page. [S]He is unsure what the proper technology to use is be-it markup/css/javascript.

Comment: @caligula I have updated the question, and I haven't done any CSS stuffs yet.

Comment: @EvgeniyNaydenov See my updated question, I haven't touched the CSS parts. What if I want this to be done in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets assume that you already have the images hardcoded on to your html document.  What you would need to do (if you want to accomplish this with PHP) is add a `style` attribute to each element. In your case, your images are held within `<a>` tags, so you'll want to position the `<a>` tag randomly and not the images...

```
function generateRandomPositions(){

  // define maximum and minimum 'top' values
  $maxTop = 1000;
  $minTop = 0;

  // define maximum and minimum 'left' values    
  $maxLeft = 1000;
  $minLeft = 0; 


  $styleProperties = array(
    'position:absolute',
    'top:'.rand($minTop,$maxTop) . 'px',
    'left:'.rand($minLeft,$maxLeft) . 'px'
  );

  return ' style="'.implode(';',$styleProperties).'" ';
}
```

The function will return a string similar to this -

```
style="position:absolute;top:10px; left:45px;"
```

Now all you have to do is call this function for each image on your page -

```
<a <?php echo generateRandomPositions();?> ><img src="...
<a <?php echo generateRandomPositions();?> ><img src="...
<a <?php echo generateRandomPositions();?> ><img src="...
<a <?php echo generateRandomPositions();?> ><img src="...
```

Your `<a>` tags will now contain random CSS positioning parameters and their images will move with them.

As I'm sure you can see, this method of using PHP to generate inline CSS properties is kind of a backwards way to do this. JavaScript would probably be the best way to get what you are looking for and there are other answers that cover it. You could initially hide your elements with CSS and then display them with the JavaScript after you have set the random positioning.

---

References -

- [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)
- [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: 1000x1000 screen? It would make 1000x more sense to use %, also, this sort of operation should not be done with PHP.

Comment: @kor - the 100opx limit was just an example I gave for the limits.  I am clearly aware that PHP is not the way to do this however the original post *was* asking about PHP - it's an alternative.

Comment: not trying to be abrasive, but his question was which technology would be best to use, he then stated that he thinks php to be the best. I'm glad that you understand this, but you should state that there are better ways.

Comment: @Lix Works as I expected, any way to prevent overlapping?

Comment: @san - That's kind of the problem with the randomization. You would have to re-generate a random location and each time check it against existing values that you have already generated. Remember to add the width and height of the element to the values to make sure there are no overlapping.

Comment: @Lix I have changed `$maxTop` and `$maxLeft` to `100` and replaced `px` to `%`. But I don't want images to appear beyond the fold. I tried changing maxTop and maxLeft to even 95%, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather simple implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/Eu8wT/

```
$('div.randomizeme').css({
    top: Math.random() * 100+'%',
    left: Math.random() * 100+'%'
});​
```

To apply this over several elements:

```
$('div.randomizeme').each(function(){
    $(this).css({
        top: Math.random() * 100+'%',
        left: Math.random() * 100+'%'
    });
});​
```

Here's the same thing without jQuery:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.randomizeme');
for (var i in elements) {
    elements[i].style.top = Math.random() * 100 + '%';
    elements[i].style.left = Math.random() * 100 + '%';
}​
```

Comment: Hey it works on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eu8wT/), but is not working for me. Can you [review it](http://synaptik.co.cc/so/12445851/KorvinSzanto)?

Comment: You're loading the script prior to loading the images, if you do it the other way around it will be fine, or you can wait for the entire page to load using `window.onLoad = function(){ }`

Comment: Moved script to just above the closing body tag (updated that link), but still that problem.

Comment: Its not working outside jsFiddle, can you provide a real world *(on a webpage)* example?

Comment: @Santosh Here is the "no jQuery" version: http://fiddle.jshell.net/dSAzp/show/ it's important to remember that you can only have ONE `window.onload` definition, so if your page has jQuery or another library that uses `window.onload`, try using `document.onload`. I should also let you know that I previously said `window.onLoad` which is incorrect, it's `window.onload`

Comment: Here's an example of never going out of the bounds of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/Jfduu/

Answer (score 1):

A solution that uses pure JavaScript (no library)

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.rand'), 
    len = imgs.length, 
    /* subtract the width/ height of images */
    w = document.body.clientWidth - 48, 
    h = document.body.clientHeight - 48;

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  imgs[i].style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * h) + 'px';
  imgs[i].style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * w) + 'px';
}
```

[**working demo**](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/tyFza)

Comment: @Ana Its working good on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/tyFza), but I don't know why it isn't working for me. Can you [review it](http://synaptik.co.cc/so/12445851/ana)?

Comment: I don't know why, but I've updated the pen and my answer. This is also simpler and I'm thinking it should work :-?

Comment: the new version works for me when I try it on your site using developer tools.

Comment: @Ana Really? I have updated the JavaScript, but it is as it was. The images appears to be overlapping each other, thus showing only one image. Did you tried it in your browser (locally)?

Comment: I ran it in the console on your site. And I think I have now figured out why it wasn't working. It said `document.body` was `null` and that's logical, since you put it in the `head`, *before* the `body`. You should put the script right before you close the `body` tag.

Comment: @Ana What was the reason you fixed the length and width of image to `48px`, it seems to work without it.

Comment: Because you said your images are `48px` x `48px` each. The ones I used are not, they are actually bigger, so that's how I scaled them down.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$images= array(
    'twitter-48.png',
    'facebook-48.png',
    'plus-48.png',
    'github-48.png'
);
$keys= range(0, count($images)- 1);
shuffle($keys);
foreach($keys as $key) {
    print "<div>{$images[$key]}</div>";
}
```

EDIT:

```
<?php
$images= array(
    array('href'=> 'http://twitter.com/', 'alt'=> 'Twitter', 'src'=> '/images/twitter-48.png'),
    array('href'=> 'http://facebook.com/', 'alt'=> 'Facebook', 'src'=> '/images/facebook-48.png'),
    array('href'=> 'https://plus.google.com/', 'alt'=> 'Google Plus', 'src'=> '/images/plus-48.png'),
    array('href'=> 'https://github.com/', 'alt'=> 'GitHub', 'src'=> '/images/github-48.png')
);
$keys= range(0, count($images)- 1);
shuffle($keys);
?>
<div class='location1'>
    <a href='<?php print $images[$keys[0]]['href']; ?>'><img alt='<?php print $images[$keys[0]]['alt']; ?>' src='<?php print $images[$keys[0]]['src']; ?>'></img></a>
</div>
<div class='location2'>
    <a href='<?php print $images[$keys[1]]['href']; ?>'><img alt='<?php print $images[$keys[1]]['alt']; ?>' src='<?php print $images[$keys[1]]['src']; ?>'></img></a>
</div>
<div class='location3'>
    <a href='<?php print $images[$keys[2]]['href']; ?>'><img alt='<?php print $images[$keys[2]]['alt']; ?>' src='<?php print $images[$keys[2]]['src']; ?>'></img></a>
</div>
<div class='location4'>
    <a href='<?php print $images[$keys[3]]['href']; ?>'><img alt='<?php print $images[$keys[3]]['alt']; ?>' src='<?php print $images[$keys[3]]['src']; ?>'></img></a>
</div>
```

Comment: There are two errors in your code, **1.** You didn't closed the php tag. **2.** You are just using texts not the images, you should do `img src` somewhere in the code. + I want the image to be scattered all over the page, not just in a coulmn.

Comment: In a bit better way, I will reiterate what @HanhNghien said; the closing tag is optional.

Comment: @HanhNghien But still in a single coulmn.

Comment: Put `<div class='location1'>...</div>` in Header, `<div class='location2'>...</div>` in Left, `<div class='location1'>...</div>` in Right, `<div class='location1'>...</div>` in Footer or **anywhere**

Comment: @HanhNghien The question was about randomizing that **anywhere**. Anyways, there are other answers that did it.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$images = array('1.gif', '2.gif', '3.gif');
$images = array_shaffle($images);
foreach ($images as $image) {
  echo "<img src='{$image}' />;
}
```

Comment: array_shaffle? Also, you didn't close your `"`. Finally, this doesn't quite answer the question posed.

Comment: Rather `bool shuffle(array &$array)`;  
I've just edited this answer, awaiting of accept.

Comment: @evg - Please do not edit code blocks from other peoples posts.  They can (and probably will) drastically change the outcome of the provided solution.  In these cases it is better to leave a comment for the OP and let them take care of it.